# Error Message as Object Required while using IE.Document.getElementById("info_window").innerText

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I am very new to VBA programming & have been trying to capture the text that gets popup on the google map when I search using GPS Coordinates (Latitude and Longitude). I have been using the website www.gps-coordinates.net.

Till now I have been able to pass the GPS Coordinates to the website input boxes and got the button clicked and the address pops'up on the google map in a box. While I am trying to get the address from the box using `IE.Document.getElementById("info_window").innerText`, I get an error message

> Runtime Error '424' Object Required

I am not able to understand which object the code is referring to. I have search the internet for a solution but couldn't find anyone facing similar kind of problem, so couldn't find a ready solution for  this. The code snippet is mentioned below:

```
Sub GetPlaceName()

    Dim btn As Variant
    Dim IE As Object, Doc As Object
    Dim sDD1 As String, sDD2 As String
    Dim vAdd As Variant
    Dim lat As Integer, longt As Integer, latrow As Integer, longrow As Integer

    latrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    longrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    If latrow <> longrow Then
        MsgBox "The number of Latitudes & Longitudes are not equal. " & vbNewLine & " PleaseCheck...."
    Else
        Range("B2").Select
        For i = 2 To latrow
            Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            IE.Visible = True
            IE.navigate "http://www.gps-coordinates.net/"
            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            Set Doc = IE.Document
            Doc.getElementById("latitude").Value = Range("B" & i).Cells.Value
            Doc.getElementById("longitude").Value = Range("C" & i).Cells.Value
            With Doc
                Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("button")
                For Each e In elems
                    If e.getAttribute("onclick") = "codeLatLng(1)" Then
                        e.Click
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next e
            End With
            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            sDD1 = IE.Document.getElementById("info_window").innerText
            vAdd = Split(sDD1, vbNewLine)
            Cells(i, "E").Value = vAdd
            IE.Quit
            Set IE = Nothing
            Set Doc = Nothing
        Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

I believe that there must be a very small error which I am not able to figure out. It must also appear to be very silly to some of you but I really need help to fix this. Hope to receive reply soon... Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: The Google Maps JavaScript API will work much better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Set IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
```

instead of

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

this never failed to work for me.